# Use SharePoint 2013 "like" button as a "Sign up" button for events

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, web-services, sharepoint-online

I'm trying to create an SP 2013 list which I'm planning to use as Events calendar and hope you'll be able to help me with some ideas.

The idea is the following:

Everyone will be able to create his own event and open it for registration to the public. The creator of the list item should be the only one able to edit and delete it. I was planning to use the "like" feature in SP 2013 as a "Sign up" button but in order to achieve that, I need 2 things -

1) limit the number of likes. Saying that every event will have different number of available seats (defined by the item creator) and employees should not be able to "like" the event any more if the limit is reached

2) send an email to the list item creator every time when someone "like" the item. The email should be smth like "*Name of the user" signed up for your event"

Unfortunately I don't have enough SP knowledge to achieve the above so I'm counting on your help and will appreaciate if you can point me the right direction. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have created such logic with custom "Likes" list".
List can have just 2 columns – List Guid, Item Guid. The standard Author field stores info about user that have added like.

The values are loaded by JavaScript client object model and users can add likes through JS COM. 
In the list item event receiver I control that user can add the like only once, and here you can check if the count of likes have reach maximum value, send email to item author.